# Error Installing Landscape Server on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, landscape

I just installed Landscape Server on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 18.04 and am getting an error when I go to the webpage.
[Here is the message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJxhj.png)

Checking the logs, I found this

> landscape-setup INFO  Schema configuration output:#012#012Loading site
>   configuration...#012WARNING: PostgreSQL has max_prepared_transactions
>   set to 0, not using two-phase commit.#012Setting up database schemas
>   (will timeout after 86400 seconds) ...#012Schema patch version: 472

Not sure if this is what is causing the issue but if so, how do I update the max_prepared_transactions?  Or could there be another issue causing my problems?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The details of the "Oops" should be in /var/log/landscape-server/appserver.log

Comment: It is saying "Unhandled error in Deferred" and then the traceback.  [Here](https://pastebin.com/FH7rE2mh) is a paste of the log.

Answer (score 0):

Last I heard, Landscape Server has to be on 16.04, 18.04 is not yet supported. Maybe that has changed as you've gotten further than I had.

E: Looks like they updated the PPA for 18.04 (as suggested by the PPA version being 19.01). I gave it a go on a fresh 18.04 server VM and got the same error you did. It doesn't appear to be related to the Postgres message. It appears the actual issue (which spawns other issues afterwards) is:

`pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData: server closed the connection unexpectedly`

E2: After looking into it further, Google suggested it could be related to available space, and sure enough, I was using a 16GB VHD with this Ubuntu install, below the minimum requirements for Landscape. Now the error of interest to me is:

`2019-03-03 15:37:03.453 ERROR landscape-quickstart Load command failed:

/usr/bin/pg_restore --disable-triggers --no-owner --data-only --host=localhost --username=landscape_superuser --dbname=landscape-standalone-package /var/lib/landscape/hash-id-databases/landscape-standalone-package.sql`

It strikes me as something Canonical should fix, but in the meantime I will try to find a workaround...

E3: I would guess it has something to do with the recent major release of Postgres 11 but the landscape-server-quickstart script installs Postgres 10.6. You might try the install on Ubuntu 18.10 although you'll typically want Landscape on an LTS install.